# Flux last() operation when empty

Tags: java, spring-webflux

I am trying solve my problem when i need to get last element (last method) of a flux but in some cases these flux can be empty and the follow error is appear

```
Flux#last() didn't observe any onNext signal
```

and this is the chain i have

```
return apiService.getAll(entry)
      .flatMap(response -> {
          if (response.getId() != null){
             //do some logic
             return Mono.just("some Mono");
          }
          else{
             return Mono.empty();
             }
          })
          .last()
          //more flatMap operators
```

I already use `switchIfEmpty()`as well but can't fix.
What is the correct implementation to verify if can call last() or skip and return a empty to terminate chain operation.

Thanks,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to [`Flux.last()`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#last--) api doc:

> emit NoSuchElementException error if the source was empty. For a passive version use [takeLast(int)](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Flux.html#takeLast-int-)

It means that, for an empty upstream Flux:

- `last()` will emit an error
- `takeLast(1)` will return an empty flux

Now, `takeLast(1)` returns a Flux, not a Mono, as last() does. Then, you can just chain it with `Flux.next()`, and it will return the only retained value (if any), or propagate the empty signal.

Note: another solution would be to use `last().onErrorResume(NoSuchElementException.class, err -> Mono.empty())`.
This would catch the error sent by `last()` internally, and then return an empty mono.
However, if you've got some code other than `last()` that can throw a `NoSuchElementException`, you might miss a problem. For this, my personal choice for your case would be to use `takeLast(1).next()`.

The following code example shows behavior of last() vs `takeLast(1).next()`:

```java
import reactor.core.publisher.Flux;
import reactor.core.publisher.Mono;

public class FluxLast {

    static void subscribe(Mono<?> publisher) {
        publisher.subscribe(value -> {},
                            err -> System.out.println("Failed: " + err.getMessage()),
                            () -> System.out.println("Completed empty"));
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        subscribe(Flux.empty().last());
        subscribe(Flux.empty().takeLast(1).next());

        // When not empty, takeLast(1).next() will return the last value
        Integer v = Flux.just(1, 2, 3)
                            .takeLast(1)
                            .next()
                            .block();
        System.out.println("Last value: "+v);
    }
}
```

Program output:

```
Failed: Flux#last() didn't observe any onNext signal from Callable flux
Completed empty
3
```

Comment: thank you @amanin. One more question, the takeLast() return a Flux, but i am interested in to have a Mono as a last() give me. What is best approach ? takeLast().next ?

Comment: thanks, i saw right now :) . thanks a lot!